# Cross Application Tracking using the Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, measurement-protocol

Hi I have a customer who is using Universal Analytics on their web page and then when you click on a link it goes into their app that is using measurement protocol.

They UA code is the same but the CID changes.

Example website:

> cid=1387132168.1487081747

When i get into the app with the same browser

> cid=47d9e140-f6ed-41c2-bd2d-9f3fb91df6b2

I suspect that Google Analytics starts a new user and session when the CID changes and just need some confirmation that that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The field [Cid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) anonymously identifies a particular user, device, or browser instance. For the web, this is generally stored as a first-party cookie with a two-year expiration. For mobile apps, this is randomly generated for each particular instance of an application install.

You might consider seeing if you cant figure out how to assign a [Uid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) and send that around between the web and mobile apps Uid will override cid.

Cid and Uid are both used to denote specific users and sessions.  So yes if it changes its a different session.